# How to compile an iOS App (IPA) to distribute it via Microsoft Intune

Tags: ios, xcode, intune

Our firm is using Microsoft Intune as MDM.

We have our first iOS App that we want to send to some devices vía Intune.

We have compiled the App for the App Store, then export the ipa file and upload it to Intune. So far so good....

We then assign the App to a group of users. However the Install process fails. Icon shows up all grey out on the device, but when you click an states "Impossible to install App. Try again later.

Just to verify, running the App on an iOS connected to the compiling Mac computer works fine, when we launch it from Xcode.

Is there any guide on how to compile or configure the ipa creation process (Provisioning profiles, certificates, etc...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like an In-House provisioned build. In-House provisioned applications can be installed on any device. However, you must have an enterprise developer account with Apple in order to create an In-House provisioning profile. These types of builds are only allowed to be distributed to employees of the business that owns the enterprise developer account.

[image]

Here's a detailed walkthrough of setting up the distribution certificate, In-House provisioning profile, etc.

https://medium.com/wso2-iot/how-to-export-in-house-developed-ios-app-as-an-enterprise-application-dc087bdd64c3

If you do not have an enterprise account, unable to get one, or intend on distributing your app to individuals outside of your organization, you only really have one other solution: Ad-Hoc provisioning. With this type of provisioning, each device must be registered in your Apple developer account and included in the provisioning profile in order for the app to install.