# IntuneMAMConfigurator for Intunes iOS sdk configuration

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, intune

I am integrating Microsoft Itunes SDK in my iOS app. The app already include Azure AD for authentication of user. However now I want my app to communicate with Intunes application and fetch its login.

The microsoft documentation has specified proper step however I am stuck with use of [IntuneMAMConfigurator tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-ios).

Can anyone tell me how to use this(IntuneMAMConfigurator) tool exactly?

Comment: You just run the tool and specify your info.plist and entitlements file.

Comment: i did the same thing. But no way to provide/specify any input to it. Some steps get executed say aruguments missing

Comment: Show the arguments you are specifying.

Comment: I am just running the file. How to do i provide argument?

Comment: The instructions are shown at step 6 `-i plistfile -e entitlements` you can also use `-o` to specify a different output plistfile

Comment: yes i read it. but do i need to run this on terminal using 'cd' command?

Comment: You need to run it in the terminal from the right directory.

Comment: When i double click the file terminal opens up, and few commands are executed automatically. And the finally - logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: You can't just click the file. You need to open a terminal and run it from the command line

Comment: should i place the file in the same heirarchy as that of info.plist?

Comment: When i run the file. The terminal dont allow me to type in. :(.  just saying [process completed]

Comment: It can be anywhere as long as you specify the Path to it when you run it

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Fixed

Comment: thanks . but how to I specify path as the terminal screen is uneditable for me.

Comment: You need to open a new terminal. You will find it under applications or use spotlight to search and run terminal

Comment: can you please elaborate this. Its saying command not found.

Comment: Something like `/path/to/IntuneMAMConfigurator -i plistfile -e entitlementfile`

Comment: thanks. GOt it finally. kshitij helped me out

Answer (score 6):

I had issues with executing the file on macOS Catalina, I had to first give the file access to execute with `chmod +x IntuneMAMConfigurator` and then run it with `./IntuneMAMConfigurator -i <path> -e <path>`

Answer (score 5):

I know it's late to answer this question, but I faced the same issue and Microsoft's documentation is no help on this. To help other folks out there here are the steps.

To run IntuneMAMConfigurator, download it from the SDK repo: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/IntuneDocs/blob/master/intune/app-sdk-ios.md

Do not try to open it by double click, this won't work.

Open Terminal and type `/path/to/IntuneMAMConfigurator -i plistfile -e entitlementfile`

/path/to/ : Type in the full path where IntuneMAMConfigurator is present.
plistfile : Copy and paste the plist file path of your project
entitlementfile : Copy and paste the file path of your entitlements file.

In addition to this if you do not want your existing plist file to change you can create a new plist file by following command:

```
/path/to/IntuneMAMConfigurator -i plistfile -e entitlementfile -o new plistFile
```

Comment: thanks for your input. however simple dragging the file first and then typing -i and then paths is more easier it seems!

Comment: do u have any idea for my other post regarding SSO?

Comment: Hi Pallavi & @prasadnikumbh can you please help me to wrap ios app using intune sdk

Comment: You mean to get the build out. This answer might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526697/how-to-compile-an-ios-app-ipa-to-distribute-it-via-microsoft-intune

Answer (score 0):

In my case this solution works for me.
Ensure the Entitlements plist is specified in the "Custom Entitlements" field of the project's "iOS Bundle Signing" options for all the appropriate Configuration/Platform combinations.

Also check, Wheather your project paths contains any space means in your path folder name having space.

Answer (score 0):

**IntuneMAMConfigurator tool**:

```
Usage 1: 
IntuneMAMConfigurator -i /path/to/info.plist -e /path/to/entitlements

Usage 2: 
IntuneMAMConfigurator -generateOpenInIcons /path/to/app.app

Optional Usage 1: 
IntuneMAMConfigurator -i /path/to/info.plist -e /path/to/entitlements -o /path/to/new/info.plist

Optional Usage 2: 
IntuneMAMConfigurator -generateOpenInIcons /path/to/app.app -o /path/to/output/directory
```